# Scroll between views like snapchat in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

This is the behavior I am seeking :

[image]

It's OK until the step 3 where the sliding cell stops after reaching the limit.

But I have absolutely no idea how to tell the parent scrollView that it should start sliding at this point !

Comment: Have you use any external library this functionality?

Comment: No I am not using external libraries

Comment: What is the structure of your views ? From what i understand you have a parentviewcontroller with a scrollview and two childviewcontroller inside that scrollview, is that correct ? How do you handle the cell sliding ?

Comment: @Justa The structure is correct. The first viewController inside the parent scrollView contains a tableView. I've added a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the cell with a handler that moves the sliding cell subview accordingly.

Comment: And what is your current behavior ? The scrollView never scrolls ?

Comment: The scrollView never scrolls. That's right.

Comment: have you implemented `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` by adding to your parent view controller the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82196/discussion-between-cherif-and-justa).

Comment: I have implemented it, it is not the right tool.